# Have arrow key KeyBindings still work even when JTextField is selected

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, key-bindings

I am using KeyBindings and am using the condition WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW so the keys always work. However, it seems that specifically arrow key (left, right, up, down) KeyBindings stop working if a JTextField has been selected.

Simply put, I would like the KeyBindings to always work no matter what JComponent has focus.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JTextField field;

    private static JFrame frame;

    private static boolean up = false, down = false, left = false, right = false;

    private static int x = 275, y = 275;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 600);
        t.setVisible(true);

        field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);

        Timer repaintTimer = new Timer(2, t);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        setUpKeyActions(t);

        frame.add(field);
        frame.add(t);

        Dimension dim = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation((dim.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2, (dim.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        repaintTimer.start();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
    }

    private static void setUpKeyActions(Test t) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                up = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                up = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                left = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                left = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                right = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                right = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                down = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(t, condition, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                down = false;
            }

        };

    }

    private static abstract class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        KeyAction(JComponent component, int condition, int keyCode, int modifiers, boolean onKeyRelease) {
            InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap actionMap = component.getActionMap();
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifiers, onKeyRelease);
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
            actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(up)
            y -= 1;
        if(down)
            y += 1;
        if(right)
            x += 1;
        if(left)
            x -= 1;
        if(x < 0)
            x = 0;
        else if(x > frame.getWidth() - 30)
            x = frame.getWidth() - 30;
        if(y < 0)
            y = 0;
        else if(y > frame.getHeight() - 50)
            y = frame.getHeight() - 50;
        g.drawRect(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.repaint();
    }

}
```

In the above code, the box moves with the arrow keys. However, if you select the text box in the upper-left corner, the box will no longer move.

**Update:**

I tried to add the KeyBindings to the JTextFields as given in the answer by @camickr, but it did not seem to work. Perhaps I am doing something incorrectly?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JFrame frame;

    private static boolean up = false, down = false, left = false, right = false;

    private static int x = 275, y = 275;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 600);
        t.setVisible(true);

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);

        Timer repaintTimer = new Timer(2, t);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        setUpKeyActions(t, field);

        frame.add(field);
        frame.add(t);

        Dimension dim = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation((dim.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2, (dim.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        repaintTimer.start();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
    }

    private static void setUpKeyActions(Test t, JTextField field) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                up = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                up = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                left = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                left = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                right = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                right = false;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                down = true;
            }

        };

        new KeyAction(condition, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true, t, field) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                down = false;
            }

        };

    }

    private static abstract class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        KeyAction(int condition, int keyCode, int modifiers, boolean onKeyRelease, JComponent component, JComponent... components) {
            InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap actionMap = component.getActionMap();
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifiers, onKeyRelease);
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
            actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), this);
            for(JComponent jc : components) {
                inputMap = jc.getInputMap(condition);
                actionMap = jc.getActionMap();
                keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifiers, onKeyRelease);
                inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
                actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), this);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(up)
            y -= 1;
        if(down)
            y += 1;
        if(right)
            x += 1;
        if(left)
            x -= 1;
        if(x < 0)
            x = 0;
        else if(x > frame.getWidth() - 30)
            x = frame.getWidth() - 30;
        if(y < 0)
            y = 0;
        else if(y > frame.getHeight() - 50)
            y = frame.getHeight() - 50;
        g.drawRect(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suspect that the text field is receiving and *consuming* the event. Have you tried to remove the corresponding key binding from that field? Or use another key, just for testing?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Well, this seems to happen particularly with the arrow keys. This is what I meant to say, but I'll edit the question to make it more clear. If I replace the keys with WASD, it works fine. I don't understand what you mean by the corresponding key binding from the field, though.

Comment: remove the key binding for arrow keys from the test field (`getInputMap`) - so it will not consume the event (obviously the text field will loose the respective functionality)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Is there any way of making the KeyBindings I have of higher priority? Because I still need the JTextFields to be functional.

Comment: a bit strange, having the arrow key execute 2 actions at the same time: move the cursor in the text field and at the same time have the box moved? Anyway, have a look at `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using KeyBindings and am using the condition WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW

There are 3 InputMaps:

1. JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED
2. JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_
3. JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW

The WHEN_FOCUSED has precedence, so you can't just add the Key Bindings to the parent panel.

So in your case you could:

1. add the bindings to the text field as well or
2. remove the bindings from the text field.

See [How to Remove Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto).

Edit:

Take a look a [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager). It will show the default properties for each component, including which InputMap(s) are used by the component.

So for the JTextField you can remove the default bindings for all text fields by using:

```
InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
im.put(keyStroke, "none"); //noop
```

The above will disable the right arrow key of all text fields. Then I believe the bindings for the parent panel of the text field will now become active.

If not you can try changing the default Action for the text field. Take a look at [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). It will show the default bindings for each component. So you can just replace the Action for a specific binding.
 Something like:

```
ActionMap am = (ActionMap)UIManager.get("TextField.actionMap");
am.put("caret-forward", yourRightActionHere);
```

If you only want to change certain text field, then you will need to get the InputMap or ActionMap from each text field component.

Comment: Hello, I tried adding the bindings to the text field as well, but I may have done something incorrectly. Please look at my update to see what I tried. Also, from what I understand, removing the bindings from the JTextFields would stop them from functioning as they would normally. Is this correct?

Comment: `removing the bindings from the JTextFields would stop them from functioning as they would normally. Is this correct?` - yes, you can only have one Action per key stroke. Not really sure what you are doing. A couple of comments. Get it working for a single text field first before trying to implement a general solution. You only need to create a single Action for each KeyStroke. The Action can be shared by all the input maps. See edit.